# Ubuntu 18.04: Why is Java CPU usage so high?

Tags: 18.04, java, cpu, openjdk, intellij

- Ubuntu version: `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`
- Java version: `openjdk version "1.8.0_212"`
- Intellij version: `2019.1.2 Community Edition`

[image]

Whenever I open Intellij, with no background processes running, I can see Java's CPU utilization goes up to ~500% and beyond. I have performed a `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Java application high CPU usage may resort from a number of reasons. Bellow are some causes:

- A poor application code with inefficient loops.
- Java Virtual Machine (JVM) memory shortage.
- Incoming workload.
  For reference purpose visit [this page](https://www.eginnovations.com/blog/troubleshoot-java-cpu-issues/).

A quick solution here will be increasing the JVM memory. This will help in the application taking more time in processing other than in Garbage Collection.
For aid on how to achieve this see the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294268/how-can-i-increase-the-jvm-memory).

Success in your solution!